# Regex for converting file path to package/namespace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Given the following file path:

```
/Users/Lawrence/MyProject/some/very/interesting/Code.scala
```

I would like to generate the following using a *single* regex replace (the root can be a constant):

```
some.very.interesting
```

This is for the purpose of generating a snippet for Sublime Text which can automatically insert the correct package/namespace header for my scala/java classes :)

Sublime Text uses the following syntax for their regex replace patterns (aka 'substitutions'):

```
{input/regex/replace/flags}
```

Hence why an iterative approach cannot be taken - it has to be done in one pass! Also, substitutions *cannot* be nested :(

Answer (score 1):

If you know the maximum number of nested folders.You can specify that in your regex.

---

For 1 to 3 nested folders

Regex:`/Users/Lawrence/MyProject/(\w+)/?(\w+)?/?(\w+)?/[^/]+$`

Replace:`$1.$2.$3`

---

For 1 to 5 nested folders

Regex:`/Users/Lawrence/MyProject/(\w+)/?(\w+)?/?(\w+)?/?(\w+)?/?(\w+)?/[^/]+$`

Replace:`$1.$2.$3.$4.$5`

---

Given the constraints this is only thing you can do

Comment: Thank you Sieg - I needed someone more confident with regular expressions than myself to confirm that!

Comment: This only appears to work with a fixed number of folders. I.e the first works with precisely 3 folders, and the latter works with precisely 5 folders. Even if it were tweaked so it did in fact match (at least in my tool it doesn't), then what about the additional periods (.) that would be introduced by the replace?

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield oops check out the edit.now it works with 1 to 3 nested folders

Comment: Thanks Anirudh, although this is still going to produce redundant periods (.) in the output for paths with fewer folders than the max.

Answer (score 1):

Input

```
/Users/Lawrence/MyProject/some/very/interesting/Code.scala
```

Regex

```
^/Users/Lawrence/MyProject/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/Code.scala
```

or

```
^/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/
```

Replace

```
\1.\2.\3
```

**Update**

This gets you closer, but not exactly it:

Regex

```
(^/Users/Lawrence/MyProject/|/Code\.scala$|/)
```

Replacement

```
.
```

Output would be:

```
.some.very.interesting.
```

Without multiple replacements in a single line and without recursive back references it's going to be hard.

You might have to do a second replacement, replacing something like this with an empty string (if you can):

```
 (^\.|\.$)
```

Comment: Same problem as Sieg's answer: This only appears to work with a fixed number of folders. I.e the first works with precisely 3 folders, and the latter works with precisely 5 folders. Even if it were tweaked so it did in fact match (at least in my tool it doesn't), then what about the additional periods (.) that would be introduced by the replace?